# The meaning of "avoir intérêt"

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, france, définition

I want to know the meaning of "avoir intérêt que"
Ex: j'avais intérêt que j'y arrive
Please translat the sentence for me too
Thanks

Comment: You already asked that question...

Answer (score 0):

"Avoir intérêt que" is not correct¹. You can say "**avoir intérêt à**". So, in correct French you should say "**J'avais intérêt à y arriver**".

However, what "j'avais intérêt que j'y arrive" means can be guessed; there are two possibilities.

1/ If the context is that of getting some place,  it means "It was in my interest to get there".

2/ If the context is that of succeeding in doing something, it means "It was in my interest to succeed".

---

¹ Suite au commentaire de **user jlliagre** (Mais comme chaque peuplade avait intérêt que son capitaine fût le meilleur [Voltaire](https://fr.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Voltaire_-_%C5%92uvres_compl%C3%A8tes_Garnier_tome18.djvu/367)) une recherche montre qu'on trouve des exemples  récents, mais pour « a intérêt que  » de 2015 à 1998 il y en a 3 mis à part 2 « y'a intérêt que » (pas correct du tout il me semble), puis on ne trouve plus d'exemples jusqu'à 1883. Le cas de « avait intérêt que » est similaire. Comme en plus le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/int%C3%A9r%C3%AAt) ne mentionne pas cette construction, il est très possible qu'elle ne soit pas jugée de nos jours comme étant de la meilleure langue. La tournure avec « à » est sans ambiguïté et très répandue, néanmoins celle avec « que » (même si elle ne semble pas très naturelle) reste compréhensible.

Comment: *Mais comme chaque peuplade avait intérêt que son capitaine fût le meilleur* [Voltaire](https://fr.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Voltaire_-_%C5%92uvres_compl%C3%A8tes_Garnier_tome18.djvu/367).